# Threaded console app throwing error, but execution carries on as normal and nothing is logged

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a small console application which has a fairly simple task of collecting realtime data from a data server and throwing it in a database. The app makes a TCP connection to a server which then holds the connection open and throws data down the pipe. The app collects it, reformats it and then chucks it in an MSSQL database.

The application is multi-threaded - on startup, I spin up a 'Collector' thread that's in charge of managing the TCP connection to the data source and throwing data messages onto an internal queue. There's a separate 'processor' thread that looks for messages in the queue, pulls them off individually and creates a database insert transaction. The initial startup thread does pretty much nothing at all once the other threads are up and running.

Everything's fairly extensively logged using NLog, both to file and to console.

The issue I'm having is that on occasion, Windows (Server 2008) throws up an error dialog similar (but obviously not the same!) to the one below. When this happens, the console logging pauses so i can see the approximate time the error is thrown. If I click 'Close the program', the app continues running as normal, but the size of the message queue rapidly goes up, as if the Collector thread has been running all along but the processor thread has been blocked. There's nothing recorded in the logs about any exceptions being thrown.

http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/7533/pleaseclosethisprogram.png

Given that I think I'm catching as many exceptions as possible and logging as far as possible, I'm stumped as to what this might be. I originally thought it might be the logging mechanism throwing an exception, but after ripping out log4net and replacing it with Nlog, I'm seeing the same behavior. This is extremely difficult to reproduce given it only happens irregularly, about twice per week. The app is written in C# .NET 4.

If anyone's got any ideas about steps I can take to troubleshoot this issue, that would be hugely appreciated.

**edit**

Ok, I've got some details from the event log, I'd completely forgotten that .NET exceptions get logged in there as well. here's the data:

```
Faulting application name: DataArchiver.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4dd027df
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x00000000
Fault offset: 0x0039b8f0
Faulting process id: 0x59c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc13358473b6da
Faulting application path: D:\DataArchiver\DataArchiver.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: f352ef11-7ffc-11e0-9cd0-005056bc0006
```

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock to me. How is your queue implemented?

Comment: Did you find anything in the Event Viewer (Control Panel, Administrative tools)?

Comment: Sounds like a StackOverflow error, and your OS is closing your application. Check Event Viewer to confirm.

Comment: I'll double-check the codebase (don't have it to hand) but I think the Queue is a standard .NET Queueing class, i'll grab the exact class name later on. I've added the Event log data to the post, it doesn't seem to be particularly helpful...?

Comment: Just checked, it's a System.Collections.Queue.

Answer (score 1):

For start, you could make sure that you catch any unhandled exceptions in your app by wrapping the entire `Main` method in a try/catch block. Also, add an event handler for the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. This will catch event thrown by your background threads. Both handlers should log the error and then allow the application to close.

If you have a thread running in background, and its `IsBackground` property is not set to `true`, it will keep your application alive. Your main program logic should also take care to notify all threads that they are supposed to finish in case of an exception, user close request or windows shutdown.

Comment: Will a try/catch around the `Main()` method catch exceptions thrown in child threads started by that method? I'll take a look at adding those things into the codebase to see if they make a difference. Ideally, I'd like this app to keep itself running as much as it possibly can, only quitting on extremely fatal errors.

Comment: @growse: no, an exception on a diferent thread will not be caught, but that's what `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` is for. But freely swallowing exceptions is not an answer also. You don't want to have your app running quietly, with no errors, only to find that it didn't actually insert a single entity to the database for more than a week. Keep in mind that it is hard to anticipate which unhandled exception (unhandled but eventually caught somewhere at the top) will leave the program in a "valid-enough" state to keep going.

Comment: It's a good point - I'd need to tie this in with some sensible alerting mechanism to let me know there's a problem. However, I don't want the app to lose data just because the database has decided to go down for 10 minutes. I'd rather let the program queue up messages until it reaches a pre-defined queue size (ie. before it runs out of memory), and then it can quit if the problem isn't resolved after then. But appreciate that exception handling is far from trivial.